# Ubuntu 13.04 won't boot after grub

Tags: boot, grub2, 13.04

I ran into a problem with Ubuntu 13.04.

I installed it without any problems. When I reboot my machine it hangs on a black screen with a blinking cursor after grub.

1. I tried recovery mode as well and it hangs at `switching to clock source tsc`.
2. I tried the nomodeset parameter for the kernel, but it results in the same.

I used a dualboot Ubuntu 12.04 & Windows 7 before, now I only want Ubuntu 13.04 alone.

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 3):

Try booting from Ubuntu install CD:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

if it doesn't work, try chrooting:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo grub-install /dev/sda1
```

Debugging grub loading:

Hold shift during boot, then hit e to edit the GRUB entry. Remove the part that says "quiet splash" and replace it with "text" to see what's happening during boot.

Have a look here: [Linux kernel hangs at 'Switching to clocksource tsc" on Pentium 4](https://superuser.com/questions/378947/linux-kernel-hangs-at-switching-to-clocksource-tsc-on-pentium-4).

and try to edit the boot entry (just add `clocksource` either with `hpet` or `acpi_pm` value):

```
clocksource=hpet quiet splash
```

If it works you might want to change in `/etc/default/grub` this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash clocksource=hpet"
```

then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: When I try to run grub-install /dev/sda it say : Path `/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting.

Comment: do you have just one partition? paste here output of `fdisk -l` or rather `df -m`

Comment: Yes I only have one partition for the system, and a second one for swap.                                                  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   242069503   121033728   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       242069504   250068991     3999744   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: I will try that, but just to be clear, the problem is right after grub. I keep you updated

Comment: So I tried your way. First of all there is a mistake it should be --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda instead of /dev/sd1. It succeeded without any issues. BUT it still does not work. I can boot into grub, select Ubuntu or Advanced Options for Ubuntu, nothing works. I still only see the blinking cursor. Any other solutions??

Comment: hmm.. that's strange. try to remove "quiet splash" from booting entry, I've updated it in the answer

Comment: I tried something similar before with the nomodeset parameter instead of text. I deleted the quiet splash. As I wrote in the first post, it stuck at "switching to clocksource tsc".

Comment: it looks like kernel issue :( you can try downgrading kernel

Comment: I could not figure out any way to downgrade the kernel within a live environment. Therefore I cannot try this method. I will install 12.10 an try an upgrade from there. Maybe this will work. I really want to try out Unity 7 and the new Nautilus with build in MTP-support.

Comment: What is your hardware vendor/configuration? you might try setting GRUB parameter `acpi off`. It might be issue of some settings in BIOS, or maybe old version of BIOS.

Comment: I have an ASUS u33jc. Should I use this parameter instead of something? Is the removal of quiet splash necessary in combination with acpi off? I also should mention that Ubuntu is installed on a Samsung 840 Pro SSD. I could try to update the BIOS an see if it changes things.

Comment: First try editing the grub entry with adding `clocksource=hpet` (I've updated it in the answer)

Comment: So, after a little of using Windows, I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 as I did before. But now, I just works right out of the box. Don't ask me why, I did not change anything at all. But I simply works.

Comment: Wow :) I'm glad, you've finally solved it.