# Ubuntu 13.04 Stuck During Boot After Grub

Tags: boot, 13.04, grub2, upgrade

I just upgraded Ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04 today. Everything went smooth until after reboot,and now at the grub menu. If I picked the first option (which says Ubuntu) it goes to a blank screen with a lot of scrolling text and then simply stops on:

```
[    5.420120 CR2:0*82000
```

I've read that many people have had a similar problem with fresh boot to 13.04: [Ubuntu 13.04 won't boot after grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287206/ubuntu-13-04-wont-boot-after-grub) || [Upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 Problem - Boots into Blank Black Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289926/upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-04-problem-boots-into-blank-black-screen)

I used these to get Ubuntu backup and working by going to advance Ubuntu options and booted into the first one. But, this is a workaround and not a fix those links offer more technical suggestions, but those are beyond my ability to comprehend. So my question is: How to fix the default Ubuntu option in grub so that it doesn't display the wall of scrolling text and freeze?

Comment: The answer provided [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/287221/169736) ends in a permanent solution, which is modifing the `/etc/defaul/grub` file. Also the second link suggest that you should need to update your kernel until the version 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the default menu selection you're not changing the version of the OS you're just changing the version of the kernel you're loading.

If that works, that's fine: It sounds like something changed in the kernel version that ships with the updated version of Ubuntu. Keep using the old kernel until a new one is released.